# Param missing error - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error in my rails application. **param is missing or the value is empty: contact**

*Home Controller*

```
def contact
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

      if @contact.save
        redirect_to root_path
        firstname = params[:contact][:firstname]
        lastname = params[:contact][:lastname]
        email = params[:contact][:email]
        message = params[:contact][:message]
        ContactMailer.contact_email(firstname, lastname, email, message).deliver
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for your message, we will be in touch soon."
      else
        redirect_to home_contact_path
        flash[:danger] = "Opps, there was a problem! Please fill out all the fields."
      end
  end

  private

    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :message)
    end
```

*Mailer/Form*

```
<div class="contact-form">
  <%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :firstname, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :lastname, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :message, required: true %>
    <%= f.submit "Get in touch!", class: "btn btn-info" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

*Contact Page*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="center-aligned">Contact Me</h1>
</div>

<div class="main-content">
  <p class="center-aligned">You can contact me via the social media links at the bottom of the site or via the contact form below.</p>

  <%= render 'home/mailer' %>
</div>
```

*Contact.rb*

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email, :message
end
```

*Server Log*

```
Started GET "/home/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-17 14:13:13 -0500
Processing by HomeController#contact as HTML
Completed 500  in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: contact):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:28:in `contact_params'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:9:in `contact'

Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (21.9ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (9.8ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (80.8ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.3ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (72.9ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.3ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (2.0ms)
  Rendered /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (135.5ms)
```

Please let me know if you need anything else. I am still learning Ruby on Rails.

Comment: can u post server log error

Comment: Server log has been added to the original post.

Comment: In console previosly to this line you should see the params that are send to the server, please put it here.

Comment: just add everything after requesting it.

Comment: have you setup the `@contact` object before showing the form ? as you can see you have `simple_form_for @contact` which expect an object @contact, so in the action that show your contact page, you have to setup `@contact = Contact.new`

Comment: Or simply u can do this way `<%= simple_form_for Contact.new do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply your form parameter is empty, reason of getting the error from there. Also, you have to define your routes.

**Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for Contact.new, url: :contact_emailer do |f| %>
```

**routes**

```
post 'contact_emailer' => "contacts#contact", as: :contact_emailer
```

Comment: do you have teamviewer?

Comment: Sorry, i just updated it, and i dnt use it. check my last update... edited in `routes` part.

Comment: I'm so confused now.

Comment: I have a question for you, Where is yr `contact` method located in what controller ?

Comment: it's located in home_controller.rb, but since read all the comments here I have moved it out into contact_controller.rb.

Comment: alright, if u moved to `contacts_controller.rb` then do it like this `post 'contact_emailer' => "contacts#contact", as: :contact_emailer`, i hope yr method named `contact` still

Comment: Now i'm getting another error. NoMethodError in Home#contact

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112205/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-andy).

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining `@contact` when you render the form.

The action that renders the form need a code similar like `@contact = Contact.new`

On the other hand, you need to define a POST method for submit the form. Contact should be your post method where the form is submited and you need another action GET with the code that I give you before.

```
 def contact
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
 end

 def create
    if @contact.save
        redirect_to root_path
        firstname = params[:contact][:firstname]
        lastname = params[:contact][:lastname]
        email = params[:contact][:email]
        message = params[:contact][:message]
        ContactMailer.contact_email(firstname, lastname, email, message).deliver
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for your message, we will be in touch soon."
      else
        redirect_to home_contact_path
        flash[:danger] = "Opps, there was a problem! Please fill out all the fields."
      end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :contacts
```

Answer (score -1):

You get this error because you try to assign params here:

```
@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
```

and since nothing has been submitted yet, and you specified that  `params.require(:contact)` you get the error.

Here's what you do: as a good rails citizen create separate method for showing the form (usually `new`) and another one for submitting it (usually `create`)

It would look little bit like this:

```
   def new 
      @contact = Contact.new # this is empty model, no data yet
   end

   def create
     @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
     # ... and all the other fancy stuff you have there
   end
```

don't forget to update your view filename to `new.html.erb` or call `render` in the controller.

It is possible to use one method to both show new form and handle request on submit but the separation to new/create is more clear.

Comment: why `contact_params ` ? and where ?

Comment: can you paste generated HTML form (from your browser)?

Comment: dude, Why `contact_params ` instead of `params` ?

Comment: The form is not generating because of my error. Sorry. But I have posted the html code for the form.

Comment: Oh, I thought this error message is after submitting the form. One sec.